# Posting changed values of a disabled control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, post, disabled-control

**EXAMPLE**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" Enabled="false" />
```

1. A textbox with value `'1'` is set to disabled.
2. The texbox value is updated to `'2'` using javascript.
3. When posted to the server the intial value `'1'` is used.

I have tried overwriting this functionality with the following VB Code:

```
Page.Form.SubmitDisabledControls = True
```

**QUESTION**

Why doesn't the updated value post to the server?

**NOTES**

The updated value post correctly `'2'` if `enabled="true"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" Enabled="true" />
```

Comment: The value is not lost. Are you changing it with javascript? However, here is a thread with your issue: http://forums.asp.net/t/1243343.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes but the problem does not occur if I remove enable="false"

Comment: Is the control in the masterpage or in a contentpage?

Comment: The control is in a content page. I wanted to submit all disabled values site wide by adding SubmitDisabledControls to master page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have ammended my question after considering your comments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what happens is if you set `Enabled = false` for some ASP control, that particular control will rendered on client-side but its class will be set as `"aspNetDisabled"` which prevents its value to be edited. I found no way to edit/change this class. So, you can't edit its value using any client-side script like JavaScript.

When you try to post its value back to server, the initial value is used which was there in server.

If you enable the control, it gets rendered and in that case you can access/edit its value as you want.

Comment: You can set `style = "display : none" ` instead of disabling it. All JavaScript functions will work perfectly fine in that case.

Comment: You are confusing `Enabled` with `Visible`. Disabled controls wil be rendered on clientside, but they don't need to be persisted in `ViewState`. You could use a hiddenfield instead to store the new value, on server you'll use this value for the `TextBox`.

Comment: The value needs to be visible. I have created a followup question here if any of you would like to continue to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096984/how-to-protect-an-asptextbox-from-user-input

Comment: I have edited my answer. The problem you explained, I have a work-around for that. I have posted it in the follow-up thread.

Comment: This is the answer I came looking for some 7 years later you helped me.