# How to protect an asp:textbox from user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, readonly, disabled-control

How to protect an asp:textbox from user input?

**DISABLE IT**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" Enabled="false" />
```

**PROTECT IT**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" ReadOnly="true" />
```

I wish to protect the textbox as above from user input but still allow the value to be updated with javascript.

This works fine so what's the problem?

**THE PROBLEM**

If a textbox is `disabled` or `readonly` the updated values will not post to the server when submitted!

**QUESTION**

How to create a textbox that can simultaneously:

- Be visible to the user.
- Be protect from user input.
- Be updated with javascript.
- Post updated value to server.

---

**ANSWER**

The conflict occurs because when you set `enabled="false"` on control it is does not pass the values to the server.

However setting `disabled` or `readonly` clientside does not cause this issue.

You can set the properties clientside by using:

In **code behind**:

```
txbx.Attributes.Add("ReadOnly", "ReadOnly")
txbx.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled")
```

or by using **client side** controls and setting them to runat server:

```
<input type="text" id="txbx" readonly="readonly" runat="server" />
<input type="text" id="txbx" disabled="disabled" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Is this vb or C#. I can tell you in Visual Basic. You can convert to C# then, there are many VB to C# converters if it is in C#.

Comment: Are you sure that the updated value does not get posted back? I have used ReadOnly = "true" and updated using jQuery and never had an issue.

Comment: @KashishArora VB is preferable thank you

Comment: @Mych yes all works fine when readonly is removed. This is a follow up post from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095888/posting-changed-values-of-a-disabled-control-in-asp-net

Comment: After a bit of experimenting standard asp:TextBox will not postback a clientside update value while ReadOnly = True yet a Telerik Texbox control does. I extensively use Telerik and therefore was confused when you had this issue.

Comment: @Mych You help is appreciated none the less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I once got out of this situation by setting the `ReadOnly` property from code-behind. You can try this once.

```
txbx.Attributes.Add("ReadOnly", "ReadOnly");
```

Add this line of code in your `Page_Load` event.

Please inform if it works for you.

Comment: Downvote was a little harsh as this actually solves the issue in the cleanest and most efficient way. It wasn't me btw.

Comment: For me, this does not work because the 'txtbx' control has not been initiated yet, and using the DetailsView.FindControl() always comes back null in the Page_Load events. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are writing this code in Page_Load() event, your control should already been initiated. If you are dynamically creating this control, write this code after initiation logic. That should work. It would be helpful if you share your piece of code. @Fernando68

Comment: REMINDER: If it is not YOUR question, do not down vote it, because it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not very well know for some reason, but ASP.NET has special property which controls if disabled controls being sent back to the server or not: [HtmlForm.SubmitDisabledControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.submitdisabledcontrols%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

So what you have to do is set this property to `true` for your `Form` control

```
<form id="form1" submitdisabledcontrols="true" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" ReadOnly="true" Enabled="false" />
</form>
```

Comment: @DreamTeK put that in your question then, as well as other details which may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did not add this property because in my previous post I was made aware that the submitdisabledcontrols does not submit updated values with javascript. So I created this post to prevent confusion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095888/posting-changed-values-of-a-disabled-control-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, in my opinion, is to have a hidden field and read that on postback instead, that way the protected textbox is just cosmetic, the actual logic is working with a hidden field.

That said, `ReadOnly = true` should still work on postback, it's only `Enabled = false` which shouldn't postback the value.

Comment: I had considered this but was hoping for a more code efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html `input` element instead, and set `runat` attribute to `server` to refer that from `server` ,like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="text2" readonly="readonly" runat="server" />
```

its value, will be sent to server after its changed on client, while it has set as `readonly`

Comment: @DreamTeK yes, i can, surely that helps, your edits had not been loaded, when i posted this...

Answer (score -1):

Beware: `<form>` does not send data for disabled inputs.

My personal solution:

- Make original field invisible with JS
- Write new field with the original value and make it disabled, just for show.

  ```
  var status = document.getElementById("ElementID");
  status.style.visibility='hidden';
  var row = status.parentNode.parentNode;
  var newCol = row.insertCell(-1);
  newCol.innerHTML = "<div style='padding-left: 6px'><input readonly='readonly' type='text' size='50' value='" + status.value + "' class='inputReadOnly'/></div>";
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Be visible to the user.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" />
```

Be protect from user input.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" Enabled="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txbx" runat="Server" Text="1" ReadOnly="true"  />
```

Be updated with javascript.
create a function and use like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a = ($("#<%=txbx.ClientID%>"));
        a.value="assas";
</script>
```

Post updated value to server.
same as above